# All valid words that must have even number of a's or even number of b's

Tags: regex

All valid words that must have even number of a's or even number of b's

Comment: Is this a request to get us to do your homework for you?

Comment: This is not a question. I suppose by including the tag "regex", we were supposed to figure out that you wanted us to write you a regular expression that fulfills your stated requirements? Sorry, Stack Overflow is not a "give me teh codez" website.

Comment: Gabe and CodyGray your both attitude is not good. See Austin reply. He did not write regular expression but guide me in right direction. that is +ive attitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend this site: http://rubular.com/. Its a sandbox for Regular Expressions where you can play around with them. It should help you solve your problem.

Comment: thanks Austin L. Tt is good way to guide. It is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this with one regular expression. For one word you'd need to do something like

```
if ((replace(/[^Aa]/g, "").length & 1) == 0)
```

Of course this highly depends on your programming language (the above would work in JavaScript)

Comment: It's a regular language (a DFA with only four states is sufficient), so it most certainly can be recognized by a single regex.